# VueJS how to listen to event from method not from template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am sending an event from a child component to it's parent. I want to intercept the signal via a method in the parent. But the listening function fires always regardless of whether an event has been emitted. Note that I am using single file components and Vue-router.

As an aside, I have found very few VueJS examples use single file components, and for a noob, transpiling from the simple Vue app in one file to multiple single file components can be confusing.

Parent:

```
<template>
 ....html here
</template>
<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  data () {
    return {
     stage: 1
    }
  },
  components: {
    Child
  },
  created: function () {
    // the following line always runs even when listen for non-existent event eg this.$on('nonsense'...)
    this.$on('child-event', this.stage = 2)
  }
  }
```

child:

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="sendEvent" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'Child',
  data () {
    return {
      response_status: 'accepted'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendEvent: function () {
      this.$emit('child-event', 'accepted')
    }
  }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: An example of multiple files and a build step - https://github.com/jonataswalker/vue-rollup-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way of setting the `on` event would be referencing the listener method directly from the place where you call the child component.

On your parent template you could do something like:

```
<Child v-on:child-event="eventIsEmitted"></Child>
```

On your `methods`:

```
eventIsEmitted: function(status) {
    if (status == 'accepted') {
        this.stage = 2;
    }
}
```